# Casting from Any to anything else fails

Tags: swift, ably-realtime

API gives me back a variable that has type `Any`. It looks like this when I print it.

```
{
  "sender" : "Kira",
  "created" : "08.05.2018",
  "text" : "Cncncm"
}
```

I tried to use `SwiftyJSON` to cast it like this `let mydata = JSON(data)` but it failes. I tried to use Swift 4 decoding technique but that failed as well. I tried to do this `let myData = data as? Dictionary<String, String>` but it fails again.

I am clueless what to do here. Any tips or solutions?

Comment: Is it `String`? What API? What does the documentation say? You may be able to use `type(of:)` to determine the actual of of the variable

Comment: It's freaking `String`. What a facepalm.

Comment:  (not laughing at you, but with you - been there)

Answer (score 1):

Finally a chance to demonstrate one of the `Codable` protocols hidden gems. Please run the following in a Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
    {
      "sender" : "Kira",
      "created" : "08.05.2018",
      "text" : "Cncncm"
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

struct SenderText: Codable {
    let sender: String
    let created: Date
    let text: String
}

let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
dayFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let date = dayFormatter.date(from:"08.05.2018")
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dayFormatter)

do {
    let sendText = try decoder.decode(SenderText.self, from: jsonData)
    print(sendText)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The sheer elegance of how easy it is to define such an intricate parser mapping a messy JSON-string to your favourite `struct` will hardly ever stop to amaze me. No matter how weird your date format looks, it is hardly more than 3 lines away from being parsed during the process.

There is something in regard to casting you should note though: In Swift, as in most object oriented languages, you can only *cast* something to something else if (and only if) it already *is* something else in the first place (but that knowledge has been lost somewhere). Since your `String` is "just" a `String` (in disguise of an `Any` maybe) you won't be able to *cast* it to anything else. However the `Codable` protocol provides you with a terrific means to `decode` from the `Strings` `Data` with astonishing ease. This process should not be mistaken as a cast, even if it looks largely the same. It is the creation and initialisation of another, more fittingly structured object from a simple piece of `Data` that you are likely to have gotten from your average web service of choice.

Great so far, at least in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it like this as it's a json string

```
let trd = yourVar as? String

if let data = trd?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

   do {
           var content = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:String]

           print(content)

      } 
      catch let error as NSError {

           print(error)
     }
}
```

Comment: Please stop suggesting `.allowFragments` if the result type is supposed to be array or dictionary. Remove the `options` parameter. And the bridge cast to `NSError` is redundant. Just `catch {` is sufficient.